# Convert string data into PTB format to train the Stanford Sentiment Analysis tool

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, sentiment-analysis, training-data

How convert string data, like a tweet, into PTB format to train the Stanford Sentiment Analysis tool?

Comment: What is the PTB format? If PTB means **Penn Treebank**, then this is not a matter of **conversion**, but **parsing**.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a matter of simply converting from one format to another. As @lenz mentioned, PTB is the output format of a parser -- this means at minimum you need to convert text to a syntactic parse. An automated parser (e.g., Berkeley/Stanford/BLLIP parser) could get you some of the way here, but (1) automatic parsers are likely awful on Twitter text, and (2) if I recall you need binarized parse trees, which means a bit of manipulation of the raw parses.

Moreover, to train a sentiment model, you need to annotate your data with sentiment. That is, for each constituent of the parse tree, you need to say what the sentiment label for the yield of that constituent is. If there were an automatic tool that does this, you wouldn't need to train a new model.

Answer (score 2):

The Stanford CoreNLP package has a java class file for converting the text in PTB format for training.

The class name is BuildBinarizedDataset